# Error : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI spring mvc without xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Getting this error while returning Html page in response from controller

org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCDemo/WEB-INF/response.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

where to put response.html?

Here is my code

```
Controller class
-----------------
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(name = "username") String username,
                             @RequestParam(name = "password") String password){

        String str = "Welcome " + username;
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("response");
        modelAndView.addObject("response",str);

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

```
Config file
------------
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.skuba.*")
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

```
This is dispatcher controller
------------------------------
public class FrontController extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {MvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the view files are in the right directory(i.e., "/WEB-INF/") try adding the following to the `MvcConfig` class.

`// Use the DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }`

Comment: Thanks. It's working. But even if I have "isELIgnored="false"" in JSP but still it shows the 
Result : ${response}
Here is my code for result jsp
`
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" language="java" %>
<html>
<body>
    Result : ${response}
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: Do mean that the expression ${response} is evaluated and printed on page? And you want it NOT to be evaluated and printed?

Comment: yes excalty i am passing value from my LoginController (as above code in question) with key "response". I want to display in html page instead of ${response}. already tried with isELIgnored="false"

Comment: "isELIgnored="false" is enough actually. I could not recreate your issue. Can you tell me which version of Spring you are using.

Comment: Spring version : 4.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: That version is fine.

Comment: Can you temporarily add your code to git ant share the code to me?

Comment: It will better if you can post this issue as a new post.